# How to return all properties with return type an interface, where the interface has inherited from another interface

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have Interfaces

```
public interface IfooBase{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
}
public interface Ifoo : IfooBase{    
    public string Email {get;set;}
}
```

and

```
public class Foo: Ifoo {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public string Email {get;set;}
}
```

My controller is following

```
[ApiController]
public class FooController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet(Name = "GetFoo")]
    public async Task<ObjectResult> Get()
    {
        Ifoo fooObject= new Foo();
        fooObject.Id = 1;
        fooObject.FirstName = "Jack";
        fooObject.LastName = "Reacher";
        fooObject.Email = "Jack.Reacher@gmail.com";
        return StatusCode(200, fooObject);
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{
    Email : "Jack.Reacher@gmail.com"
}
```

when I return an object of Ifoo type from the dotnet core's web api controller the only thing i get in response is
Email.

I dont know whats causing this. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can only return a value for the Email property? Weird, I tested with your code, I can return all properties, how do you do it?

Answer (score 2):

You are asking it to serialize an `Ifoo` which has only that one property. Change `Ifoo` to `var`.

Json.net has a different behavior vs. `System.Text.Json` for this and if you register it as your serializer you'll get the result you expected.

See this blog post for background: https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/serialize-interface-instances-system-text-json